# lightswitch deployment in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, visual-studio-extensions

I have created a lightswitch extension using VS 2012 say project name as ***SampleLSExtension***. Builded the created lightswitch project. 
 
Then, instead of installing ***SampleLSExtension.vsix*** file i have shipped  ***SampleLSExtension.lspkg*** and ***extension.vsixmanifest*** file to the following location.
***C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions{Company Name}{Control Name}{Version}***. After this i opened VS 2012 and checked, this extension is not configured VS 2012. I am not able to see my extension in Extension manager {Tools-> Extension manager and updates}.

While installing SampleLSExtension.vsix file it is configured in VS 2012.

Whether my way is correct or not? Could you please tell anyone, where i did the mistake? Is any further settings needed for configuring this in VS IDE?

Answer (score 1):

You **have to** install an extension by using its *VSIX* file. You **can't** just copy files to a location to install it.

Why are you not using the *VSIX* file? Where did you see anything that tells you to install an extension the way you've been trying to do?

Comment: Indeed,  sick with the installer. If necessary there is probably a silent install method. Also the installer does more than place files;  there undoubtedly registry entries as well.

Comment: @BradChristie Yes, you're right, there are indeed registry entries involved.